# adding value of each row using each() in jQuery

Tags: jquery, each

I achieved to store data in this format.This shows total cost of each category(ex.FOOD, CLOTHES).

```
var `obj` = {}; `obj` = {FOOD: 1000, CLOTHES: 2000}
```

The value should be overwritten after new input. For example, when "FOOD" is selected, and value of "500" is added, the `obj` should be updated to `obj = {FOOD: 1500, CLOTHES: 2000}` .

However, the value in `obj` is continuously adding up values that have been already calculated. I only want new values to be added to the total of each category.

```js
var obj = {};
$('.singleRow').each(function(rowIndex, row) {
  var key = $(row).find('select').val();
  if (!obj[key]) {
    obj[key] = 0;
    obj[key] += $(row).find('.cost').val() * 1;
  } else {
    obj[key] += $(row).find('.cost').val() * 1;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="0" class="singleRow" style="clear: both;">
    <span id="add-row" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
    <input class="tableForSpreadsheet" type="text" id="0:0">
    <input class="tableForSpreadsheet" type="text" id="0:1">
    <select class="tableForSpreadsheet form-control" id="0:2">
      <option selected="selected">FOOD</option>
      <option>CLOTHES</option>
    </select>
    <input class="tableForSpreadsheet cost" type="text" id="0:3">
  </div>
</div>
```

Since I am using `each()`, the calculation of total cost always starts from the first row. However, I only want each value to be added only once. How can I fix my code to achieve this?

Comment: Your code appears to be working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/53pLts7k/ What exactly is the issue?

Comment: how are you triggering this code?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks for the link. But it did not seem to work for me. Let's say I have first row[FOOD: 500], second row[FOOD: 300], third row[FOOD: 100]. The total for FOOD should be 500 + 300 + 100 = 900. However, my code works like this>> (500) + (500 + 300) + (500 + 300 + 100) = 2200. I am assuming because I am using each(). Do you know how I can fix my issue?

Comment: Again, that's what is already happening: http://jsfiddle.net/53pLts7k/1/. If that's not what you see in your version then you have an issue somewhere else in the code you've not shown in the question.

Comment: @madalinivascu Let's say I have first row[FOOD: 500], second row[FOOD: 300], third row[FOOD: 100]. The total for FOOD should be 500 + 300 + 100 = 900. However, my code works like this>> (500) + (500 + 300) + (500 + 300 + 100) = 2200. I am assuming because I am using each(). Do you know how I can fix my issue?

Comment: @ what event triggers your code? click event? change event?

Answer (score 0):

There should be a place where you trigger a code piece to calculate the values and update the `obj`. Also there might be another place where provides a functionality for users to add new rows and so.

There are two things coming to my mind;

1. You can calculate all the food and things from scratch. So empty the object before iterating through.
2. You can add event listeners to each row independently and update the `obj` accordingly. After updating one, you should remove its event listener not to mess with data. Otherwise, you'll need to remember the previous value and do a little more complex calculation such as removing the previous value out of `obj` and adding the new one.